# Monthly Quarterly Date Calculation in workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, date

I have the following requirement to be implemented using designer workflow.

1. Custom List will have a column with value "Quarterly" or "Monthly"
2. Based on the "Quarterly" or "Monthly" value, on the last day of that respective month, have to execute the following point (Point 3)
3. Re-set the custom list's "Status" column value to "Initial" regardless of whatever value the item's "Status" column has.

I thought I would use the following

1. Loop inside workflow
2. Pause the workflow till a date

But I am not sure how to calculate last date within workflow.

I could create a calculated column and when the item is created or modified I can pick the value, but client doesn't want a calculated column in that list.

Comment: And what is the reason the client does not want a Calculated Column? It is like wanting to buy a car but with only one gear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement , I don't think you can achieve it with Designer Worklflow. As you are planning to perform timely activity on all list items.
I can think of 3 options to achieve:

1. Create a timer job and add your logic to that.
2. Create a timer job and trigger your workflow from that.
3. If it suits you , you can add Information Policy to your list to trigger your workflow every time it met some condition.For this you need to change schedule of your 'Information management Policy' timer job. By default it runs weekly. You can schedule it to run on last date of every month.

Comment: Hi Bhaskar thanks for the response. Forgot to mention that this is a SharePoint online site.

I am thinking if Azure Jobs should help?.

Comment: Yes Azure web job will help you in case of Sharepoint Online. Option 1 and 2 is still valid. You can not use option 3 as its SPO.

Comment: Thanks, guess I should take this option as 2nd option.

Still I am thinking about requesting customer to reconsider the calculated columns. This has one advantages, save money from not using Azure.